# Handling Bank Account Transfers with Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am building a payment methodology using Stripe. My aim is to transfer money to user's bank accounts programmatically.

As I was investigating Stripe API reference, I found out Recipient object which seems being deprecated. Then I found out about StripeConnect which can achieve this, but still in beta.

My question is if there is any other way to transfer money to user's bank account without StripeConnect. Also I would like to have support in countries besides US and Canada. What is the best way to achieve this functionality by using Stripe?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this currently is with Stripe Connect and either Managed or Standalone accounts. Connect itself isn't in beta only Managed accounts are.